# Capitalize headings (h1 - h6) of posts and pages in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to create a function that will capitalize (make first letter of every word capital) in the headings of my WordPress site.

I have been able to develop a regex that I filter with
preg_match_all().

The problem is how to iterate the matches and use the ucwords() function to capitalize the headings. Finally, insert the capitalized headings back into the content.

I tried this code. The problem is how to proceed after the `if (is_array())`

```
function headings_in_the_content($content)
{
    $regexpattern = '#(?P<full_tag><(?P<tag_name>h\d)(?P<tag_extra>[^>]*)>(?P<tag_contents>[^<]*)</h\d>)#i';
    if (preg_match_all($regexpattern, $content, $matches)) {
        foreach ($matches as $regexmatches) {
            
             if (is_array($regexmatches)) {
                    foreach ($regexmatches as $regexmatch)
                        {

                        }
            }

        }
        
    }

    return $content;
}

add_filter('the_content', 'headings_in_the_content', 15000);
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's just for styling purposes, I would use css text-transform instead.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-transform

Comment: Thanks, @Ahrengot. text-transform is great, but it doesn't give me granular control. For example, I want to be able to add some exception words like "in", "if", "and", etc that I do not want to capitalize. 

Using text-transform capitalizes every first letter.